# Выдача данных в формате JSON с помощью REST API

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest

У меня есть сайт (интернет-магазин). Мне необходимо реализовать выдачу данных в формате JSON с помощью REST API.
Как связать готовый сайт с этим заданием, где можно прочитать (посмотреть) об этом?

Попробовал воспользоваться Postman с вот таким кодом:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: json/application');

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
$authors = mysqli_query($connect, query:"SELECT * FROM `books`");

$authorList = [];

while($author = mysqli_fetch_assoc($authors)){
    $authorList[] = $author;
}

echo json_encode($authorList);
```

В Posmtman ввожу такую ссылку `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/book` и получаю только html код этой страницы. Что я упустил?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не вижу html-кода в этой странице. `Content-type: application/json` а не твоя придумка.

Comment: @u_mulder Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Представленный выше скрипт не выводит никакого html-я. Правильное значение заголовка `Content-type` - __application/json__.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы. Я добавил скриншот. Такой результат получается

Comment: И что непонятного в этой надписи?

Comment: то есть, как я и написал, выводится html

Comment: Который сообщает что для доступа к данной странице нужно быть авторизованным как администратор.

Comment: Спасибо, я это вижу, мне необходима выдача данных в формате JSON. Вместо этого я получаю вот такой html

Comment: Ну может ты попробуешь (а вдруг получится) перенести этот скрипт на другой урл, который не требует авторизации?

Comment: Пробовал, то же самое

Comment: Окей. Может другие помогут.

Comment: так в постмане ты делаешь GET-запрос или выполняешь php-код?

Comment: очевидно что постманом ты тестируешь ответ сервера по вышеказанному url, но в ответ получаешь отказ от движка магазина "не авторизован", потому что тот скрывает подобные данные от неавторизированных пользователей. Вывод - либо залогиниться GET/POST запросом, либо сделать данные публичными, если они этого позволяют.

Comment: А речь о Laravel ? Данные вы из контроллера можете передавать?

Comment: Речь о Laravel, да